# Rails Create "Collection" of posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app, user's can create Designs.

Design.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

User.rb

```
has_many :designs
```

I'm trying to create a new model `Look` so user's can create Looks. The way I envision this to work is when a user goes to `/looks/new`, they have a list of all the designs they have favorited (which I have that set up that variable already) in a table format with the right column being checkboxes where the user can go through and check a few of those Designs and click Create. All the Designs that have been checked would be part of that Look.

As I haven't done this sort of thing before, I need some help accomplishing this in all aspects MVC.

Look.rb

```
has_many :designs
```

Design.rb

```
belongs_to :looks # ??? Would the model be something different since technically when you create a design it doesn't belong to a look.
```

Looks Controller

```
def new
  @designs = @user.favorites #This get's me all the designs that the particular user has favorited
  @look = Look.new # ??? Again, as I haven't set this sort of relation up before, I'm unsure.
end
```

Please let me know any other code I can provide to help out. I may even be making this sound more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration should work for you Justin:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :designs
  has_many :looks, through: :designs
end

class Design < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :designs_looks
  has_many :looks, through: :designs_looks
end

class Look < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :designs_looks
  has_many :designs, through: :designs_looks
end

class DesignsLook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :design
  belongs_to :look
  validates :design_id, presence: true
  validates :look_id, presence: true
end
```

I don't know what you want to do in the future but you might want to consider putting the user_id on the DesignsLook model, so you would not need a complex join query to retrieve all the Looks of a User. And also you implement shared Designs with all users

Comment: Thanks for the reply as always @MrYoshiji. How come you added a DesignsLook model??

Comment: It is a join model to represent the many to many relation between Deisgns and Looks

Comment: Oh alright. Well thanks a ton! Looks like I have a ton of work ahead of me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your user has many designs. New looks can have many designs. And design can belong to MANY looks, users. Smells like `has many ..., :through`
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

```
class User
  has_many :designs, through: :design_possesion
end
class Look
  has_many :designs, through: :look_designs
end
class Design
  has_many :look_designs, :design_possesion
end
```

Of course you'll have to create corresponding tables.

Comment: But for which model??